# Custom event not visible in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom

I have been trying to set up a custom activity in Journey Builder but I am not able to reach the point where the custom event icon becomes available in the journey builder interface. In other words, there is nothing to drag and drop into the journey.

I am not trying to do anything fancy, just the most basic example where I can post something to requestb.in to see how it all works and pave the way for the more sophisticated use-cases.

In terms of the set up in AppCenter, I based myself on this [walkthrough from GitHub](https://github.com/sfmc-developer-advocates/custom-activity-deskapi-node).

Files and their structure were based on the official SlaesForce documentation available [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/define-jb-extension-app-center.htm).

All of this only got me as far as being able to see my test package as an installed package in Marketing Cloud. This installed package, however, seems to be completely empty if I click on it, so in a way I am not surprised that the custom event is not avaliable in Journey Builder

Anyone has an idea what I am still missing here?

Comment: Check the application extensions in your trigger/ event, make sure to add the https to it. You can use the net work tools in chrome to see what's going wrong. Reload the tools and post a screen shot here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The most common pitfalls for custom activities and events are:**

- the activity/event isn't available via HTTPS on the default port 443
- the trigger/activity's "Public Extension"-setting in AppCenter isn't set to "This application and other installed Applications"

**Further example code:**

- [Custom Entry Event](https://github.com/mslabina/sfmc-customevent-with-transactionkey)
- [Custom Split Activity](https://github.com/mslabina/sfmc-servicecloud-customsplit)

**Additional Info:**
To easily gain information about the error that occurs you could use the Google Chrome Extension ["Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Developer Tools"](https://markus.codes/sfmc-chrome-devtools), that I created and published as open source. You can download it via the [Chrome Webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-marketing-clou/bkmmmgaljahinmpijhdggabkdngpadbn?hl=en-US).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Markus. I have checked all your suggestions but unfortunately weren't able to fix it.

Comment: Did you check out the Chrome extension? And as your Event will be hosted on another server, whose url isn't inspected, also check out the Chrome Console for any errors. If you post the error message I'm pretty sure I can help you debug further.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Markus, will try to do that.  One thing that I am still not 100% sure though is in config.json I am expected to provide applicationExtensionKey, do you know what this value should be? So far I have been using a value from the field KEY in Journey Builder Activity (in APP centre) but start to wonder whether it's the right one.

Comment: This is the key defined in [AppCenter](https://appcenter.s1.marketingcloudapps.com). After logging in, click on the created package, select the tab "Journey Builder Activity" (or "Journey Builder Trigger" if you are creating an entry event), click on the activity name and check out the value in the "Key"-field. This is the value you need to supply as application extension key in your config. The whole process is defined in the article [Create a Marketing Cloud App](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/create-a-mc-app.htm).

Comment: Ok, at least I was using the right key. I have also tried the extension but unfortunately, Error Message tab is blank for me. However when I opened the console there seem to be some errors concerning custom activities. Screenshot available [here](http://image.s7.exacttarget.com/lib/fe9613727764067b73/m/1/Error_message.JPG)

Comment: The warnings in your screenshot are related to mobile connect activities using an old version. These messages aren't related to your activity. Did you use a user from the same business unit when integrating in AppCenter? Step 3 in [Create a Marketing Cloud App](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/create-a-mc-app.htm)). Seems like the setup in AppCenter isn't done properly. If everything is configured correctly, you should see your application in the "Instance Info"-tab of the chrome extension under "Application Availability".

Comment: You were right - there were some legacy problems caused by changes in the business unit structure, so once I have tried linking it via newly created user it worked.

Comment: Great news! Glad I could help ;)